# PHP Use const/enum without giving it a value

Tags: php, enums

I am trying to partially mimick `Enum` behaviour in PHP, and I'd like to take advantage of PHP's `mixed type` aswell.

Consider this example of my code (Using PHP PDO underlying):

```
class DBH {
    /** The current database handler **/
    private $dbh;

    const SQL_NOW = 1;

    public function insert($table, $keyvaluepairs) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (";
        $values_sql = ") VALUES(";
        $values = array();
        foreach ($keyvaluepairs as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == SELF::SQL_NOW) {
                $sql .= "NOW(), ";
            }
            else {
                $sql .= "`${key}`, ";
                $values_sql .= "?, ";
                $values[] = $value;
            }
        }
        $query = substr($sql, 0, -2).substr($values_sql, 0, -2).")";
        return $this->query($query, $values);
    }
}
```

All `$value` values are possible, as long as they are allowed by `SQL` natively, **but** PDO does not restrict itself to `SQL`, it can communicate with any `RMDMS`.

Currently my `SQL_NOW` clashes with the `(int)1` value as far as I know.

How can I ensure that no value-clashing occurs, if possible, can I have an `const`/`enum` **without** value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a constant without a value, so any solution necessarily involves values that will not or can not be used "by mistake".

A practical solution would be to use GUIDs for the values of these constants, e.g.

```
const SQL_NOW = '{CD90A4D4-47EB-47A0-AFAD-B84944A06507}';
```

You also need to check against this value with the identical operator:

```
if ($value === SELF::SQL_NOW) { // three equals signs!
```

Since GUIDs that incorporate information from your network adapter's unique MAC address cannot be duplicated there is practically chance of accidental conflict.

That said, *theoretically* someone could attempt to insert this exact GUID in the database. The only way to guard against this is to use a placeholder value that cannot be used by your clients accidentally at all. This can be done with object instances, i.e.

```
$placeholder = new stdClass;
if ($value === $placeholder) {
    // This test will *never* be true unless someone does $value = $placeholder
}
```

Unfortunately object instances cannot be used as class constants, so this is not possible:

```
const SQL_NOW = new stdClass;
```

Static properties also cannot be initialized with the expression `new stdClass`, so this is not possible either:

```
static $SQL_NOW = new stdClass;
```

So this solution can only be implemented using static methods:

```
private static $SQL_NOW;

public static function SQL_NOW()
{
    return self::$SQL_NOW ?: self::$SQL_NOW = new stdClass;
}
```

You would then use the result of the function `SQL_NOW()` instead of the constant `SQL_NOW` in your code.

Comment: I agree that the chance is very low that such a value would be used, but in this case `{CD90A4D4-47EB-47A0-AFAD-B84944A06507}` can easily be a valid value for a `VARCHAR` field.

Comment: @skiwi: Not really because [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) are Globally Unique IDentifiers -- they are usually derived from globally unique MAC addresses, and even if derived randomly the chance of a collision is astronomically low. I did expand the answer with a bulletproof alternative, but it's not as nice to use.